# Image upload process usability

Tags: image, upload, usability

this is more of a usability/design approach, rather than "how" question. It is html 5 and web 2.0 age, and I want more than just "select/submit" buttons.

My question is regarding blog application: I want to have a nice way to upload and attach images to posts. Right now layout is simple: it has subject and body (for body I have BBCode editor). I can refer to images from the body using `[img]` tag.

If someone has any ideas/links how to organize image attaching to blog posts - please share!

Answer (score 1):

The best way to go about this is to check out what other people are doing to solve this usability problem. Why don't you simply check out a few free blogging sites or engines to see how they handle it? [Wordpress](http://www.wordpress.org), for example, has a few different options of embedding images in posts, and it's done fairly well in their post editor. Create a free account at [wordpress.com](http://www.wordpress.com) and play with it.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, of course I've checked that. I'm looking for other ideas and this is not just for blog, but pretty much for any user-generated content.